# Prove that $ |\frac{1}{n^z} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^z} | ≤ \frac{|z|}{\Re(z)}(\frac{1}{n^{\Re(z)}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\Re(z)}} ) $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

i.e.

$$\frac{1}{|z|}\left|\frac{1}{n^z} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^z} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\Re(z)}\left(\frac{1}{n^{\Re(z)}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\Re(z)}}\right)$$
$$  \Re(z) > 0 $$

I would use an integral since the second term (which is positive) is  $\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^{\Re(z)+1}} \,dx $.

Comment: Consider $$z \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{t^{z+1}}\,dt.$$

Comment: + Triangle inequality, that's ok

Comment: Actually, I have thought about that, but the problem is that z is complex (for the first term of the triangle inequality). There is no problem with the second one.

Comment: That's no problem (assuming that we use the real-valued logarithm for $t^z$ for $t \in (0,+\infty)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, as is customary, we use the real logarithm of $t$ for the powers $t^z,\, t\in (0,\infty)$, the inequality follows easily from the fundamental theorem of calculus:

\begin{align}
\biggl\lvert \frac{1}{n^z} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^z}\biggr\rvert
&= \Biggl\lvert - \int_n^{n+1} \frac{d}{dt}\bigl( t^{-z}\bigr)\,dt\Biggr\rvert \\
&= \Biggl\lvert z \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^{z+1}}\Biggr\rvert \\
&\leqslant \lvert z\rvert \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{\lvert t^{z+1}\rvert}\,dt \\
&= \lvert z\rvert \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{t^{\Re z + 1}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\lvert z\rvert}{\Re z}\biggl(\frac{1}{n^{\Re z}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{\Re z}}\biggr)
\end{align}

since $\lvert t^w\rvert = t^{\Re w}$ then.

Comment: Thank you, it was the first equal which was not clear but actually it is absolutely clear with logarithm.